# Trying to create an alternating image banner but it is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have three images in a banner all set with `position: absolute;` and layered on top of one another. What I was hoping to do was use the `setTimeout()` and `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` methods to alternate between the three different images being displayed. Something is happening, but not really what I wanted. Instead of a smooth transition between each image, there is simply a choppy toggle back and forth between the last image and the second, the first never appearing at all. Here is the code I am using:

```
setInterval(function()
        {
          setTimeout($("#banner_city").fadeOut(), 5000);
          setTimeout($("#banner_dispatch").fadeOut(), 5000);
          setTimeout($("#banner_vehicles").fadeOut(), 5000);
          setTimeout($("#banner_city").fadeIn(), 5000);
          setTimeout($("#banner_dispatch").fadeIn(), 5000);
          setTimeout($("#banner_vehicles").fadeIn(), 5000);
        }, 32401);
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant but just in case here is the `html` and the `css` as well. HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
  <img src="images/banner/city.jpg" id="banner_city" />
  <img src="images/banner/dispatch.jpg" id="banner_dispatch" />
  <img src="images/banner/vehicles.jpg" id="banner_vehicles" />
</div>
```

Css:

```
#banner {
  margin-top: 12px;
  position: relative;
  width: 833px;
  height: 237px;
}

#banner_city {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 833px;
  height: 237px;
}

#banner_dispatch {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 833px;
  height: 237px;
}

#banner_vehicles {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 833px;
  height: 237px;
}
```

Would anyone be able to shed some light on why this is behaving in such a buggy way? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setInterval is basically telling everything to fade-out and fade-in at the same time, which isn't what you want.

There's two approaches here: have 3 separate intervals for fading each "step", or have 1 interval with some internal counter for keeping track of what to show.

Here's the first approach:

```
function fadeOne() {
  $("#banner_city").fadeOut();
  $("#banner_dispatch").fadeIn();
};

function fadeTwo() {
  $("#banner_dispatch").fadeOut();
  $("#banner_vehicles").fadeIn();
}

function fadeThree() {
  $("#banner_vehicles").fadeOut();
  $("#banner_city").fadeIn();
}

fadeOne();
setInterval(fadeOne, 15000);

setTimeout(() => {
  fadeTwo();
  setInterval(fadeTwo, 15000);
}, 5000);

setTimeout(() => {
  fadeThree();
  setInterval(fadeThree, 15000);
}, 10000);
```

This is effectively three functions, each being called 15 seconds apart, with a 5/10 second delay on the second and third functions.

The second approach, which combines them together:

```
let count = 0;

function fade() {
  switch (count++ % 3) {
    case 0:
      fadeOne();
      return;
    case 1:
      fadeTwo();
      return;
    case 2:
      fadeThree();
      return;
   }
}

fade();
setInterval(fade, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I studied your code and explanation and that helped me understand what was going on so that I was able to then go write my own unique code to solve this problem. Thanks again, very clear and helpful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code starts all the timeouts at the same time, so they all complete at the same time. You'd have to nest them to make them to execute after each other, like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Do something
    // ...
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Do something else
        // ...
        setTimeout(...)
    }, 1000)
}, 1000)
```

This is pretty messy, so here's another approach that should do what you need:

```
// Get all the image elements
var images = $(".banner-image");

// Hide all the images
images.hide();

// Start the cycle
cycle();
setInterval(cycle, 1000);

var index = 0;
function cycle() {
  // Fade out all images
  images.fadeOut();
  // Fade in the next image
  images.eq(index).fadeIn();
  // Increment the index
  index++;
  // Reset index after cycling through all images
  if ((index % images.length) === 0) index = 0;
}
```

This code will adapt to however many image elements you include in your HTML. Here it is running on a [live demo](https://codepen.io/mathewst1/pen/VEXvaX).

PS: You can use CSS Classes to apply the same styles to multiple HTML elements.